# problem with uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following controller

```
class ActiveUsersController < ApplicationController

def edit
end
```

end

And my routes.rb is like this:

```
map.resources :active_users
```

When I try to access the controller using the url http://localhost:3000/active_users/COo8e45RqQAHr6CqSCoI/edit I got the following error:

```
NameError in Active usersController#edit

uninitialized constant ActiveUsersController
RAILS_ROOT: /Users/vintem/Documents/Projetos/Pessoal/bugfreela

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
/Users/vintem/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/vintem/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
/Users/vintem/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
/Users/vintem/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:361:in `constantize'
/Users/vintem/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:360:in `each'
/Users/vintem/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:360:in `constantize'
/Users/vintem/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:162:in `constantize'
/Users/vintem/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:443:in `recognize'
/Users/vintem/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:436:in `call'
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`resources` refers to the **model** and an assumed correlate controller named similarly. Do you have an `ActiveUser` model class? Or is it something else, say `User`? E.g.:

```
map.resources users, :controller => "active_users"
```

Check out the API docs:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html

Hard to tell exactly what's wrong from the info you've provided.

Comment: I added a ActiveUser model class but it didnt change anything